# Openid-selector and classical website registration

Tags: openid, openid-selector

I want to implement on a to-be-released website a OpenID sign-up form which looks like a classical form.

I want it to have the following fields :

- first name
- last name
- email
- password (+confirm)
- captcha

Ideally, it should not even bear any mention to OpenID.

I do not want to be an OpenID provider myself, but use an external one.

Do you know any OpenID-provider which lets me embed a form in my website for free ?

Remark : I am aware of openID-selector. In fact, I want to use it as the primary ways of signing up. However I need an alternate "normal" sign-up form because this is what many users expect. And I'd prefer to have all the signup/login process outsourced to openid providers.

Answer (score 1):

You want an OpenID Provider to provide you with the content of an iframe that will capture the user's credentials and other personal information?  You'll never find it.  All the reasonable-to-large sized OpenID Providers in fact add "frame busting" code to their pages to prevent scenarios like this because it results in poor security for the users.

That said, you should check out http://openidux.dotnetopenauth.net/ which is a demonstration of how to log users in, including new users, in a very pain-free way, using OpenID without telling the users that.  You can try the scenario of a new user who doesn't yet have a Google account but wants to create one.

Comment: Should `...authn.net` become `...auth.net`? Even with that, the URL is broken.

Comment: Hmmm... yes that was a typo.  and I'll have to check the server to see what happened to the site.